# Waiting for JSON response before returning the function?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

Hi folks I'm creating an android application's login/register part using the Android Volley Library. My application was working well, but the UI and logic were at the same class. So, I have separated them into two classes. My app makes requests to my NodeJS server using POST methods and gets JSON response. So I have tried to keep the POST request function in another class.

After separating the classes, I have a problem while waiting for response. Here is the function;

```
public String doWebRequestLogin(Context context, boolean checkLoginForm, final Map<String,String> json){
        result[0] = "FREE";
        this.context = context;

        if(checkLoginForm){

            StringRequest post = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try  {
                        Log.d("Login Response: ",response);
                        data = response;
                        res = new JSONObject(data);
                        if (res.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            int success = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(KEY_SUCCESS));
                            if (success == 1) {
                                result[0] = "LOGGED";
                            } else if (success == 0) {
                                result[0] = "LOGIN ERROR";
                            } else {
                                result[0] = "INVALID POST";
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Response Error", error.toString());
                    result[0] = "INVALID POST";
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> map = json;

                    return map;
                }
            };

            VolleyController.getInstance(this.context).getRequestQueue().add(post);

        }

        return result[0];
    }
```

This function returns result[0] as "FREE" at every time due to response time. How could it wait for the response and set result[0] according to the response? I need to know what happened while making requests.

Comment: "How could it wait for the response and set result[0] according to the response?" -- unless you are calling `doWebRequestLogin()` on its own background thread, please do not wait for the response. In other words, do not block the main application thread by waiting on network I/O.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm calling doWebRequestLogin() on the UI within an onclick function. What am I missing,  is that a bad idea to use it within a UI element?

Comment: Why is this tagged node.js?  This looks like Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm calling doWebRequestLogin() on the UI within an onclick function

Then you do **NOT** want to "wait for the response". That will freeze your UI for however long the network I/O takes, and your users will... be unimpressed.

Instead, update your UI in the `onResponse()` and `onErrorResponse()` methods.

This sort of asynchronous call, handling the results via callbacks, is core to the event-driven programming model at the heart of Android.

Comment: You are so right. Actually, my app was working fine. While making refactoring, I wanted to separate UI things and Network things but this onResponse() running time is making it hard to separate. I was just curious about how design patterns behaves in such circumstances. Anyway, I've followed what you have said.

Answer (score 2):

The request is asynchronous and you **must not** block the main thread waiting for a response. Make the method void and use a callback to handle the response once it's received.

```
public void doWebRequestLogin(SomeCallback callback, Context context, boolean checkLoginForm, final Map<String,String> json){
   [...]
   if (res.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
      int success = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(KEY_SUCCESS));
      callback.someMethod(success);
   }
}
```

For the callback:

```
public interface SomeCallback{
   void someMethod(int result); // response received, handle it
}
```

Callback may also have a return type or be generic, this depends solely on your needs...

Comment: According to the callback, some UI elements are triggered in my app. In this case, I couldn't separate UI and logic.